# I lost my Ubuntu Partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, ubuntu-12.04

I have two operating systems installed on my computer, Ubuntu and Windows 7. I reinstalled Windows 7 today and I think have a problem with the Ubuntu partition. Running fdisk -l when booted into a LiveCD, I get this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe0c5913d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   512206847   256000000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1045465086  1250263039   102398977    5  Extended ========> I think is this.
/dev/sda5      1240776704  1250263039     4743168   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

How can I restore/recuperate the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: What do you mean lost?  I'm guessing you're asking how to get the boot menu you had previously, that let you select between Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Windows, it used it own bootloader, which knows nothing about Linux. What you need to do is re-install GRUB to access both Ubuntu and Windows. [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) will provides the steps you need to fix the problem.